# PowerShell Бинарный Модуль

Tags: powershell

Я создал бинарный модуль на C# (в виде dll). Он у меня нормально импортируется в среду  PowerShell, посредством  командлет `import-module`, а также я его вижу с помощью командлет `get-module` и его командлет выполняться здесь, как говорится, всё ОК. Но у меня стоит задача это бинарный модуль импортировать на удаленную ПЭВМ. Но что бы импортировать на удаленную ПЭВМ, он должен обладать свойством "импортированным в сеанс", т.е. когда даю на выполнение командлет  `Get-Module -ListAvailable`, этот модуль невиден, естественно, `Invoke-command { import-module MyModul } -session New-PSSession -computerName 10.3.0.222`
Выдает сообщение:

> Указанный модуль "MyModul" не был загружен, так как ни в одном из
>   каталогов модулей не был обнаружен действительный файл модуля.
>
> ```
> + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (MyModul:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
> + PSComputerName        : 10.3.0.222
> ```

Мой модуль находится в директории `C:\Users\Alex_Kot\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`. Эта директория заданна в переменной среды `$env:PSModulePath`, т.е. здесь все тоже вроде как ОК.

**PS:**
Не могу понять как мне сделать модуль способным импортироваться на удаленную ПЭВМ.

Answer (score 3):

Импортируй модуль в объект сессии, вот так:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -Computername 10.3.0.222 -Credential (Get-Credential)
Invoke-Command -Session $Session {Import-Module MyModul}
Import-PSSession -Session $Session -Module MyModul
```